# Android ContentProvider create files

Tags: android, file, android-fileprovider

Lets say I have two applications `Foo` and `Bar`.
I've created a `FileProvider` for both applications and defined them in `Manifest` to allow access for applications with same signature, i.e. signed with the same keystore.

My question is: has anyone successfully done the file creation using `insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues)` from one application to the other, i.e. application `Foo` creates file with data from `ContentValues` in application's `Bar` internal storage?

Comment: You do not need `insert()` for that. You can just use `getContentResolver().getOutputStream(uri);`.

Comment: `I've created a FileProvider for both applications `. Why would two applications each have a FileProvider?

Comment: `to allow access for applications with same signature, i.e. signed with the same keystore.` ?????